# Regex to match string and not 1

Tags: regex

I am matching a string in form: `Page 1 of X` where X is a digit with the simple `Page 1 of \d+`

How can I match the same string as above except ensuring Y is a number but not a  `1` in the expression `Page Y of X`.

```
Page 1 of 41   **no match**
Page a of 41   **no match**
Page 12 of 111 **match**
```

The solution I am trying seems not to work

```
Page ^(?!(?:1)$)\d+ of \d+
```

Comment: Use a negative lookahead to "exclude" specific values that a more generic pattern can match.

Comment: Trying a lookhead with `Page ^(?!(?:1)$)\d+ of \d+` is not working

Comment: I think it should be `Page (?!1\b)\d+ of \d+` Or match `Page (?:[02-9]|[1-9]\d+) of \d+`

Comment: Sure because `$` is end of string. Is there end of string after `1` at that location? `\b` word boundary is not necessary, a space can also be used, `(?!1 )\d+`, because after the number, there must be a space. A non-capturing group around a hardcoded pattern is meaningless, `(?:1)` = `1`.